# Redirect user to the home page after deleting an account - express, mongo, axios

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios, mern

I am wondering if the code below is correct if I want to first delete the user than session associated with that user? Also, I am trying to redirect user to the home page after deleting, however if I add res.redirect("/") it says I can't set the headers:

***(node:2852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client***

```
router.delete("/", isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("DELETETETING USER", req.user.id);
  User.findByIdAndDelete(req.user.id)
    .then(() => {
      Session.findByIdAndDelete(req.headers.authorization)
        .then(() => {
          res.status(200).json({ message: "User and session was deleted" });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
    });
});
```

In the site header I am displaying the user data but after I delete the account the username is still visible. I pass user as props from main App state to the siteheader.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP request can only have one response. After you respond once to a request, you can't send a second response.

To redirect a user, you need to send a 30x response to an HTTP request. But on your code, you are already sending a 200 (success response) through this line:

```
res.status(200).json({ message: "User and session was deleted" });
```

That's why you get this error:

```
(node:2852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

To solve that you either need to substitute the "success" response with the redirection like this:

```
router.delete("/", isLoggedIn, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("DELETETETING USER", req.user.id);
  User.findByIdAndDelete(req.user.id)
    .then(() => {
      Session.findByIdAndDelete(req.headers.authorization)
        .then(() => {
          res.redirect("/");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: err.message });
    });
});
```

Or, you can keep the backend code as it is, and implement the redirection on the frontend through some Javascript logic.

---

In your case, I would just substitute the `res.status(200).json({ message: "User and session was deleted" });` with the `res.redirect("/");`, given that the "success" response seems redundant.